# How to wait for a new value in a file and print the value in Java

Tags: java, php, android

I am trying to implement a Pizza status display in Java. So the Java file is reading for values in a html file and printing it. The status can be changed by a php script:
http://easternmotormall.com/teamdroidco/server/statusUpdater.php

So the script writes the status to the file:
http://easternmotormall.com/teamdroidco/server/home.html

and the Java file prints it. But my main problem is that it needs to display the result only once and I am not sure how can I implement this.

Here is the Java code:

```
                url = new URL("http://easternmotormall.com/teamdroidco/server/home.html");


               try {
                   System.out.println("Fetching status from the server, please wait..");
                   String temp = null;
                   while(true){
                     URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
                     BufferedReader dataPtr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                     // Printing status from Status Updater
                     String status = dataPtr.readLine();
                     if (status != null) {
                         System.out.println(status);
                    }

                     dataPtr.close();
                     Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                     in2.nextLine();
                   }
               }
               catch (IOException e) {
                 System.err.println();
               }


        }
    catch (MalformedURLException  e)
        {
            System.err.println();
        }
```

I have paused the loop at the end so it doesn't keep looping.

How can I make it so that it only prints when a new status is given to the file?

PS. This is ultimately going to convert to an android app if that helps at all.

EDIT:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Here is the edited version with Threads:

```
            url = new URL("http://easternmotormall.com/teamdroidco/server/home.html");


               try {
                   System.out.println("Fetching status from the server, please wait..");
                   String temp = null;
                   while(true){
                     URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
                     BufferedReader dataPtr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                     // Printing status from Status Updater
                     String status = dataPtr.readLine();
                     if (status != null) {
                         System.out.println(status);
                    }

                     dataPtr.close();
                     Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                     in2.nextLine();
                   }
               }
               catch (IOException e) {
                 System.err.println();
               }
               statusThread statusreq = new statusThread();
               statusreq.start();
               System.out.println("After the thread...");

        }
    catch (MalformedURLException  e)
        {
            System.err.println();
        }


}




    class statusThread extends Thread {

   // 2. This is the run() method with some sample contents
   public void run() {

       String status ="", lastStatus ="";
       URL url;
       try {
       url = new URL("http://easternmotormall.com/teamdroidco/server/home.html");
           System.out.println("Fetching status from the server, please wait.. (Thread started)");
           while(true){
             URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
             BufferedReader dataPtr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
             // Printing status from Status Updater
             status = dataPtr.readLine();
            if (status != null && !status.equals(lastStatus)) {
                //new status!
                lastStatus = status;
                System.out.println(status);
            }
            else {
                // do nothing or log something
            }

             dataPtr.close();
             Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
             in2.nextLine();
           }
       }
       catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println();
       }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a thread (or if its Android you can use `AsyncTask`) to check every 30 second if the status has changed. If not - do nothing, if its changed - print it.

You could implement it like this:

```
static String lastStatus = "";

// ...

// In separate Thread or AsyncTask:

if (status != null && !status.equals(lastStatus)) {
    //new status!
    lastStatus = status;
    System.out.println(status);
}
else {
    // do nothing or log something
}
```

Comment: I am trying this right now, will post with results. Not sure why threads are being used here couldnt we do the same without threads?

Comment: I have edited the original post to include thread. Please let me know what you think and why its still the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your server is proberly implemented, that's what HTTP statuses are for.

Namely, if you use the `If-Modified-Since header` in the request with the date of your last request, you will receive either a 200 ok with a new content, or a 304 not modified with no new content.

Preferably, the value for `If-Modified-Since` is the value of the `Last-Modified` header in the response to your last request.

That's the most standard way of doing what you seek.

### edit

As for the waiting part, there are 4 options :

- use a regular polling at a defined interval of time.
- use a long polling system (a connection your server blocks for as long as possible until returning an answer)
- use a notification system (Google C2DM or a custom XMPP based implementation)
- use a bidirectionnal socket always opened

The first options is not very optimized, but is easy. The second option was the standard a while ago and is still used. There are solutions, like comet. The third option is architecturally different, but very efficient. I don't recommand the fourth option, as there is a lot to handle yourself there.

Comment: well the Server is not doing anything but just writing stuff to the file...

Its the client (Java) that should be using the if modified i think?

Comment: First request, the server gives you a file saying "Here is a file, it was modified yesterday". Next request, you ask for a file saying "i want this file _if_ it was modified since yesterday". I just checked, you server does work like that.

Comment: Yes. Actually I would be ashamed to even call it a server :)
Its just a simple php script that writes something to a file and that text has to be read from the client only once (UNLESS its changed)..

Comment: If you are going for the regular polling in android, i recommend the use of AlarmManager, which will call your service at quite regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

you can use thread for wait in java and one method of thread is sleep by which you can wait for particular duration of time....

Comment: Yes I know how sleep works but I am not sure where will it apply here. I am just pausing the script by using the scanner...